# Using SimpleXMLElement with PHP

Tags: php, simplexml

I am trying to retrieve some values from my XML file:

```
<lx:message xsi:schemaLocation="http://api.latx.corp.netapp.com/ws/schema/1.0/wsmessage.xsd">
    <lx:header>
      <lx:status>success</lx:status>
    </lx:header>
  <lx:results>
    <lx:perf_data>
       <lx:perfid>331070</lx:perfid>
       <lx:filepath>/x/eng/cs-data1/latx/prd/20151009_uploads/akshayp/AIo.data</lx:filepath>
       <lx:filename>AIo.data</lx:filename>
       <lx:datatype>perf8</lx:datatype>
       <lx:userid>akshayp</lx:userid>
 .
 .
 .
```

And I wanted to retrieve the value in `<lx:userid>`

My Code is :

```
<?php

                            $response = file_get_contents('http://www.myapi.com/myxml.xml');
                            $response = new SimpleXMLElement($response);

                            echo $response->{'lx:message'}->{'lx:results'}->{'lx:perf_data'}->{'lx:userid'};


                    ?>
```

But I am getting error like:

> Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\1\simple.php on line 116

Can someone please help, I have tried a lot to get the solution but still failing.

Thanks.

Comment: Because `lx` is a namespace and not a part of tag-name.

Comment: But I still do not get the desired output by using 

echo $response->{'message'}->{'results'}->{'perf_data'}->{'userid'};

Answer (score 1):

Use [SimpleXMLElement::getNamespaces](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.getnamespaces.php) to get the namespace uri and then [SimpleXMLElement::children](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) to get "into" this namespace.

```
<?php
$response = new SimpleXMLElement( data() );
$namespaces = $response->getNamespaces(true);
$nsLX = $namespaces['lx'];
echo $response->children($nsLX)->results->perf_data->userid;

function data() {
    return <<< eox
<lx:message xmlns:lx="foo">
    <lx:header>
        <lx:status>success</lx:status>
    </lx:header>
  <lx:results>
        <lx:perf_data>
            <lx:perfid>331070</lx:perfid>
            <lx:filepath>/x/eng/cs-data1/latx/prd/20151009_uploads/akshayp/AIo.data</lx:filepath>
            <lx:filename>AIo.data</lx:filename>
            <lx:datatype>perf8</lx:datatype>
            <lx:userid>akshayp</lx:userid>
        </lx:perf_data>
    </lx:results>
</lx:message>
eox;
}
```

Comment: The call to `->getNamespaces()` is unnecessary. If you want to make your code robust against changes to how the file is formatted, find the URL from the `xmlns:lx` attribute and hard-code it; if you don't mind fixing it later, use `->children('lx', true)` and PHP will just match based on the prefix.